# How to migrate bundleConfig.cs from project asp.net mvc to asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to migrate bundleConfig from an old asp.net project mvc to asp.net core

I added in startup.cs:

```
app.UseBundling (
                // as we rebased the static files to / static (see UseStaticFiles ()),
                // we need to pass this information to the bundling middleware as well,
                // otherwise urls would be rewrited incorrectly
                new BundlingOptions
                {
                    StaticFilesRequestPath = "/static"
                },
                bundles =>
                {
                    bundles.AddJs ("/bundles /jquery")
                        .Include ("/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");

                    bundles.AddCss ("/bundles/jquery")
                        .Include ("/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");

                    // we use LESS in this demo
                    bundles.AddCss ("/site.css")
                        .Include ("/less/site.less");

                    // defines a Javascript bundle containing your Vue application and components
                    bundles.AddJs ("/app.js")
                        .Include ("/js/components /*.Js")
                        .Include ("/js/app.js");
                });
```

Comment: seems fine to me. Make sure it uses the right using and namespaces and edit the paths so there are no spaces between (ie "/bundles/jquery" not "/ bundles / jquery" )  and then call them in your views.

Comment: if we have a bundleConfig in asp.net mvc:
bundles.Add (new ScriptBundle ("~ / bundles / jquery"). Include (
"~ / Scripts / jquery- {version} .js"));

bundles.Add (new ScriptBundle ("~ / bundles / jqueryval"). Include (
"~ / Scripts / jquery.validate *"));
bundles.Add (new ScriptBundle ("~ / bundles / bootstrap"). Include (
"~ / Scripts / bootstrap.js"));
bundles.Add (new StyleBundle ("~ / Content"). Include (
"~ / Content / bootstrap.css",
"~ / Content / bootstrap.min.css"
));
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
}
how to  migrate in asp.net core ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net core, `bundleconfig.cs` is gone.

Follow the steps below to add bundling and minification

1. Install the [bundler and minifier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) in visual studio
2. Add `bundleconfig.json` to you solution
3. Based on your bundles modify file, something like below

> ```
> [  
>   {  
>     "outputFileName": "wwwroot/bundles/bootstrap",  
>     "inputFiles": [  
>       "Scripts/bootstrap.js"  
>     ]  
>   },  
>   {  
>     "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",  
>     "inputFiles": [  
>       "wwwroot/css/site.css",
>       "Content/bootstrap.css"  
>     ],  
>     "minify": {  
>       "enabled": true,  
>       "renameLocals": true  
>     },  
>     "sourceMap": false  
>   },  
>   {  
>     "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/semantic.validation.min.js",  
>     "inputFiles": [  
>       "wwwroot/js/semantic.validation.js"  
>     ],  
>     "minify": {  
>       "enabled": true,  
>       "renameLocals": true  
>     }  
>   }  
> ]
> ```

4. You can automate the bundling and minification as part of build process as well with dotnet bundle command ( However this part I have not done yet, so not idea on this)

Answer (score -1):

You would have to create a cs file in App_Start

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace EnterYourProgramsNameSpaceHere
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {  
            //Add your bundles here 
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/myStyle")
            .Include("~/Content/styles.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myjs")
             .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.js"));
        }
    }
}
```

in startup.cs
add this line

```
 BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

You have to make sure that the spacing in your file paths is removed, in your example the program may have an issue finding your js/css files.

you can look up more info here : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862

Comment: This solution can use at asp.net mvc

Comment: I am using dotnet core  and this is exactly how my bundle config looks.

Comment: This solution can be fixed the issue but "System.Web.Optimization" package use is highly discouraged in ASP.NET core